# java.lang.Math—is “within 1 ULP” exclusive or inclusive?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

`java.lang.Math` docs say for many functions, such as [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-):

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result.

But I haven't been able to find what does this mean precisely. Is it exclusive or inclusive? In other words, if the exact result can be represented with a double, will the returned value contain exact result or it may still be off by 1 ULP?

For example, can we rely on `Math.pow(3.0, 2.0) == 9.0`? I know using equality comparison is almost always a bad idea for doubles, so I am mostly asking out of curiosity and to be able to point people to their mistakes (or reassure them) when they do something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fyi,

> The quality of implementation specifications concern two properties,
>   accuracy of the returned result and monotonicity of the method.
>   Accuracy of the floating-point Math methods is measured in terms of
>   ulps, units in the last place. For a given floating-point format, an
>   ulp of a specific real number value is the distance between the two
>   floating-point values bracketing that numerical value. When discussing
>   the accuracy of a method as a whole rather than at a specific
>   argument, the number of ulps cited is for the worst-case error at any
>   argument. If a method always has an error less than 0.5 ulps, the
>   method always returns the floating-point number nearest the exact
>   result; such a method is correctly rounded. A correctly rounded method
>   is generally the best a floating-point approximation can be; however,
>   it is impractical for many floating-point methods to be correctly
>   rounded.
>
> Instead, for the Math class, a larger error bound of 1 or 2 ulps is
>   allowed for certain methods. **Informally, with a 1 ulp error bound,
>   when the exact result is a representable number, the exact result
>   should be returned as the computed result; otherwise, either of the
>   two floating-point values which bracket the exact result may be
>   returned.**
>
> For exact results large in magnitude, one of the endpoints of the
>   bracket may be infinite. Besides accuracy at individual arguments,
>   maintaining proper relations between the method at different arguments
>   is also important. Therefore, most methods with more than 0.5 ulp
>   errors are required to be semi-monotonic: whenever the mathematical
>   function is non-decreasing, so is the floating-point approximation,
>   likewise, whenever the mathematical function is non-increasing, so is
>   the floating-point approximation. Not all approximations that have 1
>   ulp accuracy will automatically meet the monotonicity requirements.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Comment: Oh, I have no idea how I missed that part when reading it. Anyway, that answers the question perfectly. I've edited it a little bit.